# Modalbox help requested

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two webpages on my site that utilize the modalbox CSS/JS script.

This is the one that works:
http://www.miguelonenterprises.com/modalbox/modalboxtext.htm.
It's a pano image encased in a modal box script. That works just fine.

This is the one that doesn't work:
http://www.miguelonenterprises.com/modalbox/modalboxtext2.htm.
What I want to have this do is open two separate modal boxes containing two separate images. 
Clicking the button beneath Modal Example will yield a modal box with no content.
Clicking the button beneath Modal Example2 will yield nothing.

I can manage through CSS and HTML just fine, but when it comes to Java Script I have no idea.

What I would like to see happen is, if possible, an HTML document and a separate CSS document.

Any suggestions on how to make modalboxtext2.htm work?